# Why are my deque elements moving around?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am implementing a simple Tree class to use in a parser, where I need to traverse the structure of the parse tree and build it up incrementally.

This is a stripped-down version of the class that demonstrates the issue (executable in [this repl.it session](https://repl.it/MabD/2)):

```
template <typename T>
class Tree {
  T val;
  std::deque<Tree<T>> children;

 public:
  Tree() {}
  Tree(T value) : val(value) {}
  Tree(T value, std::deque<Tree<T>> children) : val(value), children(children) {}

  std::deque<Tree<T>> getChildren() { return this->children; }

  void appendChild(T value) {
    this->children.push_back(value);
    // this->children.emplace_back(value);
    std::cout << "Appended child to node with value " << this->val << ".\n";
    printChildren();
  }

  void printChildren() {
    std::cout << "children for " << this << "(" << this->val << ")"
              << ": { ";
    for (auto &child : this->children) {
      std::cout << &child << "(" << child.val << ") ";
    }
    std::cout << "}\n";
  }
};
```

For each node, the children are stored in a `std::deque` so children can be added to either end. In testing my class, I am finding that I cannot rely on the structure produced by building up the tree incrementally as opposed to all-at-once with an initializer list.

Here's some code to exercise the class and show what's happening:

```
std::cout << "Constructing Tree\n\n";
Tree<int> t(1);
t.appendChild(2);
t.getChildren()[0].appendChild(3);

std::cout << "\n\nPrinting tree from main\n\n";
t.printChildren();
t.getChildren()[0].printChildren();
```

This has the following output:

```
Constructing Tree

Appended child to node with value 1.
children for 0x7ffe9fd41820(1): { 0xb69080(2) }
Appended child to node with value 2.
children for 0xb694a0(2): { 0xb696b0(3) }


Printing tree from main

children for 0x7ffe9fd41820(1): { 0xb69080(2) }
children for 0xb698c0(2): { }
```

As you can see, the addresses of the node with the value `2` are different each time they are printed out. When it's first appended to the `1` node, it has the address `0xb69080`. After it gets its own children, it has the address `0xb694a0`. Then, when it's accessed from the `main` function, it has the address `0xb698c0`.

Additionally, it seems that when it gets moved it somehow loses its children. The last line should show that the `2` node has a single child with value `3`.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose your problem is here

```
std::deque<Tree<T>> getChildren() { return this->children; }
```

`getChildren()` return a **copy** of children.

Try with

```
std::deque<Tree<T>> & getChildren() { return this->children; }
// .................^
```

to return a reference to the internal `children`, if you want modify it using the returned value.

I mean: if `getChildren()` return a copy of `children`, with

```
t.getChildren()[0].appendChild(3);
```

you append a child with value `3` to the first element of the copy of `children` returned by `getChildren()`.

This copy isn't saved so it's a temporary value that is destroyed immediately after, losing the `3` child appended.

Comment: Thank you! I was going down the path of thinking I needed to implement move/copy constructors, but returning by reference is what I wanted to do.